# Merge two dataframes based on if comma split elements are substrings of another column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df1` as follows:

| company_name | industry_keywords |
| --- | --- |
| Looney Tunes | Chemicals, Electrical Equipment |
| The Simpsons | Information Technology, Software & Services |
| Soylent Green | Tobacco, Beverages |
| Initech | Pharmaceuticals, Health Care |
| Resident Evil | Technology |
| Hooli | Oil and Gas, Energy |
| Weeds | Technology, Food Products |
| Fringe | Manufacturing |

To split `industry_keywords` column, I use `df1['industry_keywords'].str.split(',', expand=True)`

Out:

```
                        0                      1
0               Chemicals   Electrical Equipment
1  Information Technology    Software & Services
2                 Tobacco              Beverages
3         Pharmaceuticals            Health Care
4              Technology                   None
5             Oil and Gas                 Energy
6              Technology          Food Products
7           Manufacturing                   None
```

df2:

| label | industry_keywords |
| --- | --- |
| first tiers | Food Products, Tobacco |
| second tiers | Energy, Chemicals, Manufacturing, Electrical Equipment |
| third tiers | Software & Services, Financials, Insurance, Retail Banking, Technology |

I want to map `label` from `df2` to `df1`, if `industry_keywords` in `df2` which is split by `,`, are contained in `industry_keywords` in `df1`, which also split by comma.

The expected result will like this:

```
    company_name  ...                       label
0   Looney Tunes  ...  second tiers, second tiers
1   The Simpsons  ...                 third tiers
2  Soylent Green  ...                 first tiers
3        Initech  ...                         NaN
4  Resident Evil  ...                 third tiers
5          Hooli  ...                second tiers
6          Weeds  ...    third tiers, first tiers
7         Fringe  ...                second tiers
```

How could I do that? Maybe I should create a `dictionary` for `df2`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) first, then merge with convert index to column for avoid lost values, aggregate by `join` and add to original `df1`:

```
df11 = df1.assign(industry_keywords = df1['industry_keywords'].str.split(', ')).explode('industry_keywords')
df22 = df2.assign(industry_keywords = df2['industry_keywords'].str.split(', ')).explode('industry_keywords')
```

---

```
s = (df11.reset_index()
         .merge(df22, on='industry_keywords')
         .groupby('index')['label']
         .agg(', '.join))

df1 = df1.join(s)
print (df1)

   company_name                             industry_keywords  \
0   Looney Tunes              Chemicals, Electrical Equipment   
1   The Simpsons  Information Technology, Software & Services   
2  Soylent Green                           Tobacco, Beverages   
3        Initech                 Pharmaceuticals, Health Care   
4  Resident Evil                                   Technology   
5          Hooli                          Oil and Gas, Energy   
6          Weeds                    Technology, Food Products   
7         Fringe                                Manufacturing   

                        label  
0  second tiers, second tiers  
1                 third tiers  
2                 first tiers  
3                         NaN  
4                 third tiers  
5                second tiers  
6    third tiers, first tiers  
7                second tiers
```

For remove duplicates use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = (df11.reset_index()
         .merge(df22, on='industry_keywords')
         .drop_duplicates(['index','label'])
         .groupby('index')['label']
         .agg(', '.join))

df1 = df1.join(s)
print (df1)
   company_name                             industry_keywords  \
0   Looney Tunes              Chemicals, Electrical Equipment   
1   The Simpsons  Information Technology, Software & Services   
2  Soylent Green                           Tobacco, Beverages   
3        Initech                 Pharmaceuticals, Health Care   
4  Resident Evil                                   Technology   
5          Hooli                          Oil and Gas, Energy   
6          Weeds                    Technology, Food Products   
7         Fringe                                Manufacturing   

                      label  
0              second tiers  
1               third tiers  
2               first tiers  
3                       NaN  
4               third tiers  
5              second tiers  
6  third tiers, first tiers  
7              second tiers
```

Comment: Many thanks, for the output of the first row, we got two `second tiers` labels which are duplicated, could we just keep one?

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question, if industry keywords in `df2` after splitting by comma, are substrings or exact same as keywords in `df1`, then match them. For example, let's say HSBC's `industry_keywords` are `Banking, Financials Services`, I hope it match to `third tiers` as its `label` since `third tiers`'s `industry_keywords` element `Financials` are substring of `Financials Services`, is it possible to do that?